# How to get facebook, twitter profile(name ,image) in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I have implemented facebook and twitter for ios6, but I'm not getting user details like name, email, image. Would help me anybody for this? Below is my code:

```
-(IBAction)facebook
{   
    SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];


    if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
    {
        SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

            [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
            {
                NSLog(@"Cancelled.....facebook");

            }
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
            {
                NSLog(@"Posted....facebook");
            }
                break;
        }};

    [fbController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ipadicon_72x72.png"]];
    [fbController setInitialText:@"Check out this article."];

    //[fbController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/"]];
    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Comment: **`SLComposeViewController`** is not used for retrieving user information.

Answer (score 0):

See this info on using the Twitter framework and how to get information from Twitter, specifically, see **Step 7**.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_twitter-framework_twrequest/